# nosplit stack overflow when cross compiling in Go 1.5.1

Tags: go

I'm trying to cross compile my Go project on windows/amd64 for linux/386, but get a "nosplit stack overflow" error. I followed the instructions that are outlined [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5). With `GOOS=linux` and `GOARCH=386`, my `go env` looks as follows:

```
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=linux
set GOPATH=C:\dev\gopath
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=0
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-fPIC -m32 -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
```

The complete error I get when running `go build` is:

```
runtime.cgocall: nosplit stack overflow
508     assumed on entry to runtime.cgocall (nosplit)
464     after runtime.cgocall (nosplit) uses 44
460     on entry to runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit)
272     after runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit) uses 188
268     on entry to runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit)
108     after runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit) uses 160
104     on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit)
64      after runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit) uses 40
60      on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit)
8       after runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit) uses 52
4       on entry to runtime.acquirem (nosplit)
-12     after runtime.acquirem (nosplit) uses 16 runtime.cgocallbackg: nosplit stack overflow
508     assumed on entry to runtime.cgocallbackg (nosplit)
460     after runtime.cgocallbackg (nosplit) uses 48
456     on entry to runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit)
268     after runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit) uses 188
264     on entry to runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit)
104     after runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit) uses 160
100     on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit)
60      after runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit) uses 40
56      on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit)
4       after runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit) uses 52
0       on entry to runtime.acquirem (nosplit)
-16     after runtime.acquirem (nosplit) uses 16 runtime.cgocallback_gofunc: nosplit stack overflow
508     assumed on entry to runtime.cgocallback_gofunc (nosplit)
496     after runtime.cgocallback_gofunc (nosplit) uses 12
492     on entry to runtime.cgocallbackg (nosplit)
444     after runtime.cgocallbackg (nosplit) uses 48
440     on entry to runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit)
252     after runtime.exitsyscall (nosplit) uses 188
248     on entry to runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit)
88      after runtime.exitsyscallfast (nosplit) uses 160
84      on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit)
44      after runtime.writebarrierptr (nosplit) uses 40
40      on entry to runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit)
-12     after runtime.writebarrierptr_nostore1 (nosplit) uses 52
```

Other target configurations that do work are `GOOS=windows GOARCH=386` and `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64`, but `GOOS=linux GOARCH=386` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for the mailing list or filing an issue.

Comment: Ah yes I think you're right. For anyone interested in this, see the filed issue [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12764).